# Customize/change keyboard buttons in iOS7, while using PhoneGap/Steroids

Tags: iphone, cordova, ios7, user-controls, uikeyboard

I'm part of a team building a mobile web app using AppGyver Steroids (PhoneGap). We are having an issue with the iOS7 keyboard displaying a very faint "Done" button on the keyboard when the user is operating in a text area or an input select. I suspect this is a problem that is actually global in our app, but these are the instances where I have observed them.

I've searched and searched for a solution or how to "customize" the keyboard in order to make this "Done" button more obvious, but I haven't found any solutions yet. Can anyone point me in the direction of how to adjust the "Done" button or any other keyboard/input controls?

Attached are two screenshots showing the issue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeFYM.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h11IH.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [the issue on github](https://github.com/AppGyver/scanner/issues/9)? It's now fixed. They'll be including the option for custom colours in the near future.